# Perform assertions on sweet alerts in protractor 6.0, angular 7 and sweet alert 2.0

Tags: protractor, angular7, sweetalert2

After I register a user a sweet alert comes out saying whether i was successful or not. I am not able to assert the same using protractor.

I've tried the answers in the related older posts, searched for documentations, found none.

My spec is:

```
    it('should go to login page, navigate to register page and register new user', async () => {
        const loginButton = element(by.id('loginButton'));
        await loginButton.click();
        const registerUserButton = element(by.id('registerUserButton'));
        await registerUserButton.click();
        // register page
        const name = element(by.id('usersName'));
        const password = element(by.id('password'));
        const confirmPassword = element(by.id('confirmPassword'));
        const email = element(by.id('email'));
        const number = element(by.id('number'));
        const gender = element(by.id('gender'));
        const submitButton = element(by.id('submitButton'));
        // giving values to form data input fields
        await name.sendKeys('testUser');
        await password.sendKeys('testUser123');
        await confirmPassword.sendKeys('testUser123');
        await email.sendKeys(new Date().toDateString().split(' ').join('') + new Date().getTime() + '@gmail.com');
        await number.sendKeys('9712312323');
        await gender.sendKeys('male');
        await submitButton.click();

        // checking alert
        const alertDialog = await browser.driver.switchTo().alert();
        expect(await alertDialog.getText()).toEqual('Success!! You\'ve successfully registered');
    });
```

the sweetalert code is :

```
    Swal.fire({
        type: 'success',
        title: 'Success!! You\'ve successfully registered',
        text: 'You\'re provided with 50 free loyalty points. Welcome to Star Hotel',
        timer: 50000,
        confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
      });
```

Error:
 - Failed: no such alert
    (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

But the automation takes place fine and the user gets registered and an alert does pop out with the given successful message.
I didn't find any material regarding using locators for sweet alerts, but i am assuming at the core it is still javascript alert.

Comment: Share your htlm of the alert. and confirm whether the alert in not inside a frame.

Comment: I've not used any html for alert. if it helps I've uploaded the sweetalert code though.